# Flutter / Android Studio: How to show types in code completion?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, code-completion

[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlkAo.png)

Android Studio doesn't show types when using code completion, but VSCode does.

[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIwJt.png)

As we can see, VSCode show types when using code completion. Is there any settings in Android Studio to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have Flutter and Dart plugins installed and configured properly in Android Studio?

Comment: All plugins is fine, and the code runs fine. So I think there should be some settings to display the type when code completing.

Comment: Could be a problem with handling Dart classes. Something similar when IntelliJ won't show your errors as project errors when using Dart but works fine with Java. Looking into that currently.

Comment: Probably works as intended. After using autocomplete and hovering over a parameter, editor knows & shows the type of the hovered over parameter, just doesn't include in autocomplete. Seems like a design choice, not a bug. I've looked through github issues for dart autocomplete, also AS board of all issues, none concern this specific "problem".

Comment: Weird. I got the same issue